# Dagger 2 - cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a problem with Dagger 2 dependency injection. I'm using it in Android project but in a java-library module and in unit testing.

ApiTestModule.kt

```
@Module
class ApiTestModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("testDatasource")
    fun provideGithubTestDatasource(): GithubDatasourceImpl {
        return GithubDatasourceImpl(Mockito.mock(GithubService::class.java))
    }
}
```

TestComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApiTestModule::class])
interface TestComponent {
    fun inject(test: GithubDatasourceImplTest)
}
```

GithubDatasourceImplTest.kt

```
class GithubDatasourceImplTest {

    @set:[Inject Named("testDatasource")]
    lateinit var datasource: GithubDatasourceImpl

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        val component = DaggerTestComponent.builder()
                .apiTestModule(ApiTestModule())
                .build()
        component.inject(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun test_create() {
        checkNotNull(datasource)
    }
}
```

module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    rootProject.ext.apiGithubDependencies.each {
        add(it.configuration, it.dependency)
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

My error

error:

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] hr.thekarlo95.api.github.GithubDatasourceImpl cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
    public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                         ^
      hr.thekarlo95.api.github.GithubDatasourceImpl is injected at
          hr.thekarlo95.api.github.GithubDatasourceImplTest.setDatasource(p0)
      hr.thekarlo95.api.github.GithubDatasourceImplTest is injected at
          hr.thekarlo95.api.github.di.TestComponent.inject(hr.thekarlo95.api.github.GithubDatasourceImplTest)
```

I cannot get this to work and error message doesn't really help. If I remove `fun inject(test: GithubDatasourceImplTest)` from `TestComponent` everything compiles but then I cannot inject dependencies to my unit test.

Comment: Is this in an instrumented test in the androidTest source set, or do you really mean a unit test in the test source set? If the latter, you should not be using Dagger but instead just create your mock objects directly. It also makes little sense to use Dagger in a Java library module in an Android project.

Comment: No. This is just plain JUnit(4.12) test in a java-library module so no Android related stuff can't be done in this module. I guess I could make factory for my api service but I wanted to use Dagger trough out my whole application stack. Dagger, in theory, is not an Android library so I don't see any reason to not use it here. I guess creating it directly for testing purposes is an option. I am just baffled that this doesn't work even though I did it in a way described by Daggers documentation.

Comment: Of course you can also use Dagger with vanilla Java. There's just zero reason to do so in this case. You're creating this large test harness for the sake of injecting a mock that you could just create right here in the test.

Comment: Have you tried using `@field` instead of `@set`?